# Display word/pdf/excel etc. files in browser. (Asp.net , C#.net 2008)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a requirement where in need to display the Pdf / Word doc(any version) or excel in the browser. Something similar to the GMAIL feature. How can I achieve this?
I am using Asp.net with code behind as C#. Application is in 2008

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

[How To Write Binary Files to the Browser Using ASP.NET and Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306654)

It covers, PDF, Word, Excel and a variety of image file formats.

Comment: If you want to add an option for user to download instead of displaying the file in the browser, add this to the response header. Response.AddHeader( "Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + filename + "\"" );

Comment: I have tried this solution to show .docx files using Application/msword as content type of the response, but it does not have worked. Do anyone have any ideas?