# view XLSX file in browser C#

Tags: c#, excel, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I want to view the XLSX file in browser just like we read the PDF file there.
What plugin or code should i use to achieve it?

I am running the web site in intranet and all the users has the office installed in their PC. And they want to view the file in browser instead of downloading and then view it. The browser i am targeting are IE and chrome.

Let me know comments. Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549929/display-word-pdf-excell-etc-files-in-browser-asp-net-c-net-2008

Comment: @karthi        I have given shot on the code but it displaying open/save dialog in IE. It does not open the file in browser. I believe i must be installing some plugin in browser to do so. But which plugin??