# want to open the files in another page may be image, text, doc, PDF etc, when the link(filename) is clicked, in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am making an application which shares files to the user in asp.net c#...
I have a grid with column username and filename with a link

Now I want that when I click on filename(can be text, images, doc, PDF) the file should open on different page

**My code for aspx page is as below**

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="3"
        CssClass="grid" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" 
        BorderWidth="1px" onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
        <RowStyle ForeColor="black" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="File Name">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FileName") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Who shared">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UserName") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                <ItemStyle Width="200px" />
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandArgument='<%#((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex%>'
                        Text='<%# Bind("FileName") %>' CommandName="ViewImages" ></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#669999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

How to open the file in other page so that user can see the content of files online????

Comment: I think you can get your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9255427/c-sharp-target-blank-in-a-linkbutton

Answer (score 0):

You can use handler for opening or downloading any format file. & for new page give target="_blank" to your link. Please find the handler code as here: 
http://pastie.org/6221636

& call it like `'../MyHandler.ashx?ID=filename.txt'`

If you have only issue with opening the new tab have look to [How to open a page in a new tab in the rowcommand event of gridview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798264/how-to-open-a-page-in-a-new-tab-in-the-rowcommand-event-of-gridview)

Comment: I can open the .txt  files online with the code in http://pastie.org/6221636 but not able to open .doc file online. The save as window will open in case of.doc files

Comment: i have commented             if (forceDownload)
            {
                context.Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition",
                     "attachment; filename=\"" + name + "\"");
            }
            if (type != "")
                context.Response.ContentType = type;

Comment: try to use Response.TransmitFile(file.FullName);

Comment: if you comment these lines it will not work as you need to mention the header & response type

Comment: if i will not comment then i have to download the files... but i want to display the file's content without downloading it

Comment: where i have to write Response.TransmitFile(file.FullName);

Comment: replace it context.Response.WriteFile(path); with context.Response.TransmitFile(path);

Comment: i want like http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2008/01/11/Preview-Word-files-%28docx%29-in-HTML-using-ASPNET-OpenXML-and-LINQ-to-XML.aspx

Comment: the difference is here: context.Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition",
                     "inline; filename=\"" + name + "\"");, it uses inline. anyways this much I can do. Thanks.

Comment: ya i know... but the output is same

Comment: i have also gone through the below link  but i can see save as window. i want to display the file content in the web page only http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549929/display-word-pdf-excell-etc-files-in-browser-asp-net-c-net-2008?answertab=active#tab-top